# what happens while creating objects differently in inheritance in java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

here is a question related to inherince, i was asked during an interview. Anybody can explain me what happens in the 4 cases of object creation that given below. Can anybody help me with this. Thanks in advance

```
class A {

    int i = 10;

    void printHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi in A");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    int k = 20;

    void printHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi in B");
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();// 1.a.k is possible?
        A a = new B();//2.
        B b = new A();//3.b.i is possible?
        B b = new B();//4.
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try adding code to try accessing `a.k` and `b.i`, and did it work?

Comment: Did you try to compile this code?

Comment: First thing when learning OO - Avoid Meaningless Names like `A`, `B`, etc.  Instead replace them with meaningful names like `Animal` and `Budgie`.   So, is `Animal a = new Budgie()` allowed?  (yes, since a Budgie is an Animal).   Is `Budgie B = new Animal()` allowed ?  (no, since an Animal might not be a Budgie - there could be other Animals than Budgies).

Comment: 1. no 2. directly, no. with reflection yes 3. compilation error 4. yes (assuming `Test` and `A` are in the same package as `B`, otherwise no).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 2. with cast yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the four cases only 3 are valid.

```
A a = new A();
A a = new B();
B b = new B();
```

In Java inheritance you can create an instance of a subclass and assign to a super class but not the other way `B b = new A();` around (there will be a compilation error) because the sub class will inherited from the super class so all method are either run from the super class of the from the subclass if overridden.

If you invoke the `printHi` method you can see what exactly happening.

1. For `A a = new A();` the `printHi` will print `Hi in A` because its an instance of class `A`
2. For `A a = new b();` the `printHi` will print `Hi in B` because its an instance of class `B`
3. For `B a = new B();` the `printHi` will print `Hi in B` because its an instance of class `B`